# WordPress add default widgets to widgets area

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to setup some default widgets areas and add to them some default widgets when my theme is activated.

On a fresh WordPress install I got some widgets in the first sidebar 
( search, recent posts, archives, meta area), 
I am using `unregister_widget()` to remove those widgets, 
now I cannot find a way to add widgets to those sidebars via functions.php.

Could you help me, please?

Thanks for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757461/how-to-populate-widgets-on-sidebar-on-theme-activation

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

[`unregister_widget`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget) is going to completely remove the widget from the system making it unavailable for use. What you need to be doing is removing/adding widgets to the sidebar, not unregistering them. There is a good post on the WordPress specific forum: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars

The basic idea is to manipulate the widgets array stored in the options table.

```
$widgets = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' );
var_dump($widgets);
```

If you look at that `var_dump` it should be pretty obvious what is happening. The tricky part is that all the widgets have numeric suffixes so that multiples can be used.

Comment: Thanks but I am sure that I have read already that above post. I am trying to design a theme for release it in the WordPress theme directory. I am not completely sure if I have to customize the widgets area in that way in order to get the theme accepted.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question than you one you started with.

Comment: I am sorry then. The original question is: I got widgets area in my theme and I want to populate them with some default widgets. In order to create some widgets sections in the theme, like a search form in header of the site instead than in the <aside>, and some more. With the possibility to remove and/or replace them via wp-admin.

Comment: I am not sure why it should be a completely different question though